# Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.1 Show in File or Show in Project Structure dialog

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.1



Show in File 
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

This is the error I face whenever I get the gradle build synchronized.
Looking for help.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow :)
Please read this guidelines before asking questions.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

According to library doc, 
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

you should use this in dependencies in your build.gradle file

```
compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.6.1'
```

Comment: thank you....even if i use this dependency i get the same error. Is there any other solution.

Comment: sorry but its working in my case, may be you need to check the version of your build gradle tools I use this classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the dependence via Android Studio interface.

1. Go to Build > Edit Libraries and Dependencies;
2. Click the "+" icon on the right upper corner;
3. Search for `io.socket`and, in the list, select `io.socket:socket.io-client:0.6.3` and click OK.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, but I just thought I could help someone